# Knockout.JS : How to use events in custom binding

Tags: knockout.js

The following code will work on ealier KO versions(2.x) but fails in new versions (3.x). Clicking the hyperlink should call function showSectionName in view model. The error I'm getting is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$data' of undefined
```

Check my fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/c2fe9bs8/1/)

Check very similar version which works with KO 2.x [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/NkqmK/)

My HTML:

```
    <div style="width:200px">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" data-bind=" template: { name: 'itemTmpl', foreach: sections, templateOptions : { select: showSectionName }}"></ul>

    <script id="itemTmpl" type="text/html">
        <li role="presentation" data-bind="bootstrapHyperlink: { action: $data.select, params: [ $data ] }">
        </li>
    </script>

</div>
```

My script:

```
        $(function () {

        ko.bindingHandlers.bootstrapHyperlink = {
            init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
                var elt = "<a href='#'>" + viewModel.name + "</a>";
                $(element).append(elt);

                var options = valueAccessor();
                var newValueAccessor = function () {
                    return function () {
                        options.actions.apply(context, options.params);
                    };
                };
                ko.bindingHandlers.click.init(element, newValueAccessor, allBindings, bindingContext);
            },

        }

        Section = function (id, name) {

            var self = this;

            self.id = id,
            self.name = name
        };


        function viewModel() {
            var self = this;
            self.sections = ko.observableArray(
            [
            new Section(10, "Section 1"),
            new Section(20, "Section 2"),
            new Section(30, "Section 3")
            ])

            self.showSectionName = function (item) {
                alert("You clicked the section " + item.name);
            }

        }
        ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically I think the problem you are having is with `templateOptions` there is no mentioning about it in template binding docs and this issue looks somewhat to the point https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/365

I updated the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/c2fe9bs8/4/

To avoid templateOptions you may use `$parent` special property to access your viewModel like this:

```
<li role="presentation" data-bind="
    bootstrapHyperlink: { action: $parent.showSectionName, params: [ $data ] }
"></li>
```

It is a matter of opinion but it may also be easier to just bind to click event  since you are already using jQuery and remove event handler if node is removed:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.bootstrapHyperlink = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var options = valueAccessor();

        var link = $('<a href="#">' + viewModel.name + '</a>');

        $(element).append(link);
        link.on('click', function () {
            options.action.apply(bindingContext, options.params);
        });
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
            link.off('click');
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        ko.bindingHandlers.bootstrapHyperlink = {
            init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
                var elt = "<a href='#'>" + viewModel.name + "<span class='badge'>" + viewModel.id + "</span></a>";
                $(element).append(elt);

            },

        }

        Section = function (id, name) {

            var self = this;

            self.id = id,
            self.name = name
        };


        function viewModel() {
            var self = this;
            self.sections = ko.observableArray(
            [
            new Section(10, "Section 1"),
            new Section(20, "Section 2"),
            new Section(30, "Section 3")
            ])

            self.showSectionName = function (item) {
                alert("You clicked the section " + item.name);
            }

        }
        ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
    });
</script>
```

html:

```
        <li role="presentation" data-bind="bootstrapHyperlink: { action: $index.select, params: [ $index ] }, click:$root.showSectionName">
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```